# Odd results using the COMBIN function

Tags: excel, numbers, excel-formula, precision, worksheet-function

I am a mathematics student and was given a proof detailed in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86093/why-is-n1-choose-k-n-choose-k-n-choose-k-1).

Out of curiosity I tried setting that up in a an Excel table with columns as N and rows as K, so that:

```
=COMBIN(R$6,$B16)-COMBIN(R$6-1,$B16)-COMBIN(R$6-1,$B16-1)
```

should equal `0`. For the most part it does but sometimes I get odd results. For example:

```
=COMBIN(110,35)-COMBIN(110-1,35)-COMBIN(110-1,35-1)=0
```

and

```
=COMBIN(110,45)-COMBIN(110-1,45)-COMBIN(110-1,45-1)=0
```

but

```
=COMBIN(110,40)-COMBIN(110-1,40)-COMBIN(110-1,40-1)=633318697598976
```

Can somebody tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid the answer has to be the lack of precision in Excel (15 digits max) but maybe that is not really a good enough answer.

Excel’s =COMBIN() function for `A2` (say 110) and `B2` (say 35) can be broken down as:

```
=FACT(A2)/(FACT(A2-B2)*FACT(B2))
```

The top part of the image below shows this (and confirms your results!):

[image: SO18746815 example]

The bottom part breaks that formula down into its components, showing that the largest element has a value 1.5882E+178. That is well within Excel’s limit for formulae of +/-1.7976931348623158e+308 but presumably is actually something between:

15882455415227300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

and

15882455415227500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

which I guess is the problem.

What puzzles me is that sticking with 110, the discrepancies arise only 29 times in the `B2` range 1-109 – but for any explanation of that it may be best to revert to Mathematics!

Answer (score 0):

There is a special `COMBIN` bug in Excel which has been present for many many years (Excel 2006 or earlier and still in Excel 365) and is not obviously related to the division of large numbers since it happens with small integers when giving integer results.

This only seems to turn up in the real world when doing comparisons with 0, or using the `MOD` function.  So if this is important to you, you need to round the outcome when dealing with small integers, or allow some flexibility in equality tests without comparing to 0.

- You point out `=(COMBIN(110,35)-COMBIN(110-1,35)-COMBIN(110-1,35-1)=0)` gives `FALSE`
- but trying `=(COMBIN(110,35)=COMBIN(110-1,35)+COMBIN(110-1,35-1))` gives `TRUE`

There are much smaller examples, and the first is:

- `=(COMBIN(9,3)-COMBIN(8,3)-COMBIN(8,2)=0)` giving `FALSE`
- `=(COMBIN(9,3)=COMBIN(8,3)+COMBIN(8,2))` giving `TRUE`

or even more simply

- `=(COMBIN(9,3)-84=0)` giving `FALSE`
- `=(COMBIN(9,3)=84)` giving `TRUE`
- `=(FACT(9)/(FACT(3)*FACT(6))-84=0)` giving `TRUE`

The TRUE result is the desired behaviour.

More often than not, Excel's COMBIN function manages to give the correct integer.  But in some cases it gives a value marginally below or above the correct integer, typically one or two floating-point precisions above or below, and then tries to hide the fact it does: `=COMBIN(9,3)-84` says `0` but in `=(COMBIN(9,3)-84=0)` it actually calculates a number `-1.421E-14` to compare with `0`.

Some small examples of the bug:

- `COMBIN(9,3)` and `COMBIN(9,6)` calculate `84  -1.42E-14`
- `COMBIN(10,4)` and `COMBIN(10,6)` calculate `210  -2.84E-14`
- `COMBIN(11,5)` and `COMBIN(11,6)` calculate `462  -5.68E-14`
- `COMBIN(12,6)` calculates `924  -2.27E-13`
- `COMBIN(14,6)` and `COMBIN(14,8)` calculate `3003  -4.55E-13`
- `COMBIN(15,3)` and `COMBIN(15,12)` calculate `455  +5.68E-14`
- `COMBIN(15,7)` and `COMBIN(15,8)` calculate `6435  -9.09E-13`
- `COMBIN(16,4)` and `COMBIN(16,12)` calculate `1820  +2.27E-13`
- `COMBIN(16,8)` calculates `12870  -1.82E-12`
- `COMBIN(17,5)` and `COMBIN(17,12)` calculate `6188  +9.09E-13`
- `COMBIN(18,6)` and `COMBIN(18,12)` calculate `18564  +3.64E-12`
- `COMBIN(18,7)` and `COMBIN(18,11)` calculate `31824  -3.64E-12`
- `COMBIN(18,9)` calculates `48620  -7.28E-12`
- `COMBIN(19,7)` and `COMBIN(19,12)` calculate `50388  +7.28E-12`
- `COMBIN(19,8)` and `COMBIN(19,11)` calculate `75582  -1.46E-11`
- `COMBIN(20,5)` and `COMBIN(20,15)` calculate `15504  -1.82E-12`
- `COMBIN(20,8)` and `COMBIN(20,12)` calculate `125970  +1.46E-11`

Your particular example is way beyond integer precision, but even the much smaller `COMBIN(110,3)` calculates `215820  +2.91E-11`