# Subtle difference in the results of these calculations: anyone know why (just out of interest)?

Tags: excel, formulas

I was doing a "percentage change between two numbers" calculation, and I initially wrote it as (using Excel 2013):

```
=(NEW NUMBER - OLD NUMBER)/OLD NUMBER
```

I changed it to:

```
=NEW NUMBER/OLD NUMBER -1
```

.. to test to see if it was any faster with a large spreadsheet. Like I often do, I checked to see if the generated numbers were all equivalent (using a coerced `CellColX = CellColY` formula), and about 80% of them were, but others weren't -- by a tiny amount. I watched the action in the Evaluate Formula tool and expanded out the decimal places in the cells to where it was returning all 0's.

For instance, `OLD NUMBER = 10.44` and `NEW NUMBER = 10.86` resolves to `0.0402298850574713` using the first method, and `0.0402298850574712` using the second method.

However, `OLD NUMBER = 13.17` and `NEW NUMBER = 10.44` resolves to `-0.207289293849658` using either method.

(The `OLD` and `NEW` numbers are genuine 2-place decimals.)

Mainly for OCD sake, is there a known reason for this? And is there any significance for very sensitive calculations?

Comment: See [Excel's precision for a specified number is confined to 15 significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113, This can also help

Comment: That explains it. Thanks for the pointers. I doubt anything I do would be doing would be affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a known reason for this?

As explained in Comments, Yes:

> As with other spreadsheets, Microsoft Excel works only to limited accuracy because it retains only a certain number of figures to describe numbers (it has limited precision). Excel nominally works with 8-byte numbers by default, a modified 1985 version of the IEEE 754 specification[1] (Besides numbers, Excel uses a few other data types.[2]) Although Excel can display 30 decimal places, its precision for a specified number is confined to 15 significant figures, and calculations may have an accuracy that is even less due to three issues: round off,[3] truncation, and binary storage.

(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel).)

> is there any significance for very sensitive calculations?

Also Yes, and I suggest not just for very sensitive calculations, rather often where very large or very small numbers are involved in calculations. However because 'very large and 'very small' for normal scales are at the astronomical or anatomic level they are not very often encountered by Excel users. Though there are plenty of examples on SO, eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748447/1505120) and for [Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28102086/1505120).

Where these approximations cause problems on a regular basis is, as you have noted, in comparisons. Without rounding results that *should be* (mathematically) the same may not be and `=EXACT` or just `=` may return `FALSE` falsely.